# Github action passing variables to a file

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

I have to make sure to:

- run the `setTimeout1000.js` file, and take the result and assign it to a variable `MY_VAR_1000`.
- run the `setTimeout5000.js` file, and take the result and assign it to a variable `MY_VAR_5000`.

Then take these two variables and pass them to the `MakeTable.js` file, take the result and write it to the `README.md` file

This is currently written to the file: `$MY_VAR_1000` `$MY_VAR_5000`

Can you give me a hand?

Test.yaml

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test-javascript:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run my script 1000
        run: |
          node ./test/setTimeout1000.js
        env:
          MY_VAR_1000: ${{ steps.my-step.outputs.my-output }}

      - name: Run my script 5000
        run: |
          node ./test/setTimeout5000.js
        env:
          MY_VAR_5000: ${{ steps.my-step.outputs.my-output }}

      - name: Write test results to README.md
        run: |
          node ./MakeTable.js >> README.md
        env:
          MY_VAR_1000: $MY_VAR_1000
          MY_VAR_5000: $MY_VAR_5000

      - name: Commit and push changes
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
          git config --global user.name "Your Name"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Test results updated"
          git push origin main
```

MakeTable.js

```js
console.log(process.env.MY_VAR_1000, process.env.MY_VAR_5000);
```

setTimeout1000.js

```js
const startTime = performance.now();
let callbackCalled = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  callbackCalled = true;
}, 1000);

const endTime = performance.now();
const timeTaken = endTime - startTime;

const json = {
  startTime,
  endTime,
  timeTaken,
  callbackCalled
};

console.log(json);
```

setTimeout5000.js

```js
const startTime = performance.now();
let callbackCalled = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  callbackCalled = true;
}, 5000);

const endTime = performance.now();
const timeTaken = endTime - startTime;

const json = {
  startTime,
  endTime,
  timeTaken,
  callbackCalled
};

console.log(json);
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Any error messages?